# Collapsible toolbar with a tab and a viewpager cant be collapsed by viewpager fragments containing listview

Tags: listview, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

My Layout contains a Collapsible toolbar a tab and a view pager...
I placed listview wraped in a NestedScrollView but this cant collapse my toolbar, I tried replacing it with RecyclerView still layout cant collapse.
I tried placing many 20 buttons vertically and this is able to collapse the toolbar 
I have tried several examples on github and several solutions on stackoverflow but all have proved futile
Much will be appreciated if am able to get a solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

             <ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.9"
android:src="@drawable/babe" />



        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:tabTextColor="#03A9F4"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#0288D1"
            app:tabContentStart="72dp" />



        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@null"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />



    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment_one with the listView

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView         
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/profilestatus_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="@null"
    android:divider="#03A9F4"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Fragment_two with Recycler_View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="500dp"
android:fillViewport="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Dummy_Fragment which contains the buttons and it is able to collapse the toolbar

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="YO YO"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="YO YO"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="YO YO"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="YO YO"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="YO YO"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="YO YO"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="YO YO"
    />

</ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

All help will be appreciated...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a `NestedScrollView`

Just remove it and everything will work.

**UPD_0:**

Also try to set `ViewPagers` height to `match_parent`

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

**UPD_1:**

Try also to add  `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` to `TabLayout` and `ImageView` which are inside yours `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Also make sure that you use latest versions of `design`, `suport-v7` and `recycler-view` libraries.

Comment: the updated answer is still not giving me the results...:(

Comment: Thats really strange... Some times ago I made this functionality in Eclipse and AndroidStudio and everithing was OK... All can I do - give you a link to my gitHub repo with working exaple of collapsingToolbar with viewPager with RecyclerView: https://github.com/mohaxspb/MaterialTemplate

Comment: Wooow u put a smile on ma face... :) finally got it working

Comment: I was able to achieve it by adding app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" to the imageview and also removing the NestedScrollView around the recyclerView as you suggested...i have posted a working solution ...cant upvote because my reputation is low Thanks fam.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working solution

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

             <ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.9"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
android:src="@drawable/babe" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:tabTextColor="#03A9F4"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#0288D1"
            app:tabContentStart="72dp" />



        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@null"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />



    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then for the fragments remove the nextedScrollView as suggested by @mohax

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```